# How to check if a program is configured to run as administrator?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, administrator, runas

It seems there are tons of threads asking how to check if a prorgam is running as admin or how to set a programto run as admin in windows, but my question is How can I check to see if a program is configured to run as admin without it actually running? I need to be able to check this in an automatic fashion too.

I know I can just right click an exe and check if a program is configured to run as admin, but I need a way to automatically check that since an app I'm running needs to know if a certain .exe is configured to run as admin or not and make a decision based on that property.

Comment: There are two places in the UI to tell if an executable or shortcut is configured to run as administrator. Open the properties for the file/shortcut, and the two places are the Advanced button, and the Compatibility tab. The settings made in these locations are not the same, but have the same effect. The Compatibility settings will be stored in the registry HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers. The Advanced flags are set, I believe, as properties bound to the shortcut itself.

Comment: That registry key is perfect! Thanks! HKLM version of the appcompatflags/layers is for properties of prorgams set for all users, and HKCU version is just for the current user. I never would have guessed this.

Comment: I'll turn that into an answer for now, but I want to test to see if you can read the properties of a shortcut (for the Advanced > Run as Admin flag) in command to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two places in the standard Windows UI to tell if an executable or shortcut is configured to run as administrator.

Open the properties for the file/shortcut and then...

1. For **shortcuts** only click the Advanced button and see the Run as Administrator flag.
2. For both **executable files** and **shortcuts** open the Compatibility tab.

The settings in these two locations have the same effect, but are not the same.

The first is a property of the shortcut and is bound to the shortcut. You can test this by setting the property on a shortcut in a network location, and then running the shortcut on a different computer. You will be prompted for elevation before the shortcut runs.

The second (Compatibility) is stored in the registry of the computer it is set on, and settings made on one computer will not be automatically visible on another computer without some other mechanism to propagate these settings. These are stored in two locations in the registry for either per-user or all-user application:

All users: `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

Per-user: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

These can be read programmatically and in scripts using the standard Registry-ready components available in the preferred language.